# Writing data to sequential text file with java

Tags: java, validation

There is a text file 'clients.txt' having following contents:

```
100 James Green 123.45
200 Sue Magenta 12345.67
```

It has two records. In the first record '100' is account No., 'James' is FirstName, 'Green' is LastName and '123.45' is balance.

The code below is 'AccountRecord.java' file containing the above fields and routine set get methods:

```
  public class AccountRecord {
  private int account;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private double balance;

  // no-argument constructor calls other constructor with default values
  public AccountRecord() {
    this(0, "", "", 0.0); // call four-argument constructor
  } // end no-argument AccountRecord constructor

  // initialize a record
  public AccountRecord(int acct, String first, String last, double bal) {
    setAccount(acct);
    setFirstName(first);
    setLastName(last);
    setBalance(bal);
  }  // end four-argument AccountRecord constructor

  // set account number   
  public void setAccount(int acct) {
    account = acct;
  } // end method setAccount

  // get account number   
  public int getAccount()

  return account;
} // end method getAccount

  // set first name   
  public void setFirstName(String first) {
    firstName = first;
  } // end method setFirstName

  // get first name   
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  } // end method getFirstName

  // set last name   
  public void setLastName(String last) {
    lastName = last;
  } // end method setLastName

  // get last name   
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }   // end method getLastName

  //set balance  
  public void setBalance(double bal) {
    balance = bal;
  }    // end method setBalance

  // get balance   
  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  } // end method getBalance
} // end clas
```

The code below is 'CreateTextFile.java'. It has one code line:  'output = new Formatter( "clients.txt" );', to instantiate the formatter object from 'clients.text' format:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.SecurityException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.deitel.ch17.AccountRecord;

public class CreateTextFile
{
    private Formatter output; // object used to output text to file

    // enable user to open file
    public void openFile()
    {
    try
    {
    output = new Formatter( "clients.txt" ); // open the file
    } // end try
    catch ( SecurityException securityException )
   {
    System.err.println(
    "You do not have write access to this file." );
    System.exit( 1 ); // terminate the program
   } // end catch
    catch ( FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException )
   {
    System.err.println( "Error opening or creating file." );
    System.exit( 1 ); // terminate the program
} // end catch
} // end method openFile

// add records to file
public void addRecords()
{
    // object to be written to file
    AccountRecord record = new AccountRecord();

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.printf( "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n",
    "To terminate input, type the end-of-file indicator ",
    "when you are prompted to enter input.",
    "On UNIX/Linux/Mac OS X type <ctrl> d then press Enter",
    "On Windows type <ctrl> z then press Enter" );

    System.out.printf( "%s\n%s", 
    "Enter account number (> 0), first name, last name and balance.",
    "? " );

    while ( input.hasNext() ) // loop until end-of-file indicator
    {
        try // output values to file
        {
        // retrieve data to be output
        record.setAccount( input.nextInt() ); // read account number
        record.setFirstName( input.next() ); // read first name
        record.setLastName( input.next() ); // read last name
        record.setBalance( input.nextDouble() ); // read balance

        if ( record.getAccount() > 0 )
        {
            // write new record
            output.format( "%d %s %s %.2f\n", record.getAccount(), 
            record.getFirstName(), record.getLastName(),
            record.getBalance() );
        } // end if
        else
        {
            System.out.println(
            "Account number must be greater than 0." );
        } // end else
    } // end try
        catch ( FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException )
        {
        System.err.println( "Error writing to file." );
        return;
    } // end catch
     catch ( NoSuchElementException elementException )
    {
        System.err.println( "Invalid input. Please try again." );
        input.nextLine(); // discard input so user can try again
    } // end catch

    System.out.printf( "%s %s\n%s", "Enter account number (>0),",
        "first name, last name and balance.", "? " );
    } // end while
} // end method addRecords

 // close file
    public void closeFile()
    {
    if ( output != null )
        output.close();
    } // end method closeFile
}
```

The last portion of the code for main method is as:

```
public class CreateTextFileTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        CreateTextFile application = new CreateTextFile();

    application.openFile();
    application.addRecords();
    application.closeFile();
    } // end main
}// end class CreateTextFileTest
```

When I run this class and try to enter a new record I get the  message as:

```
run:
To terminate input, type the end-of-file indicator 
when you are prompted to enter input.
On UNIX/Linux/Mac OS X type <ctrl> d then press Enter
On Windows type <ctrl> z then press Enter

Enter account number (> 0), first name, last name and balance.
? 300 Har Par 112.235
Enter account number (>0), first name, last name and balance.
? ^z
Invalid input. Please try again.
Enter account number (>0), first name, last name and balance.
?
```

Being new to programming I am confused that why this input is invalid. I need help to rectify this code or to rectify my input. The whole code has been submitted so that the problem can be judged minutely. I am using Netbean IDE 8.0 and jdk-8u5-windows-64.

Comment: You're asking people to browse a lot of code and figure out where the problem is. Most of your code is unrelated to the problem. Include just the code needed to reproduce the problem, and more people will read your question.

Comment: @DonBranson I assume because the input prompt says to use Ctrl+Z to terminate input. Although according to http://superuser.com/questions/291224/equivalent-to-d-in-bash-for-cmd-exe actually typing Ctrl+Z into CMD won't produce an EOF.

Comment: You're right. Saw that after commenting, and deleted my comment.

Comment: After you press CTRL-Z, must you press enter? Or does it output "Invalid input. Please try again." immediately after pressing CTRL-Z? Do you want the user to press enter after CTRL-Z, or is it just supposed to exit?

Comment: On pressing CTRL-Z the file 'clients.txt' is cleared, ie all the records are erased, after it pressing the enter it outputs "Invalid input."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : fix mistake

`Ctrl+Z` is not a bullet proof method under windows. You'd better (as account number must be > 0) say :
`To terminate input, enter 0 and Enter`. Then immediately after the line

```
record.setAccount( input.nextInt() ); // read account number
```

add

```
if ( record.getAccount() == 0 ) { return; }
```

Comment: I have added your lined of code. Entering 0 and pressing enter, I am not getting any invalid input message. I get the BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but there is no output and contents of 'clients.txt' are cleared off. Kindly give me some further suggestion.

Comment: @user3678356 Sorry, I forgot to replace `>` with `==`  - post updated

Comment: Hi  Serge Ballesta, the great!!!, your answer has given me success, the program is giving the right output and all the problem is over.